# Entity Framework does not add / save to database

Tags: entity-framework

I searched alot about my problem, but I hadn't found anything!

I created a database and a table and I connect my Form with EntityFramework to those..

when I type data informations and click on Add button, Database doesn't add new row ...

(these are my codes)

Main code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class BuyForm : Form
    {
        public BuyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void BuyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        notebookEntities database = new notebookEntities();



        private void buyGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BuyForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            buytbl tbl = new buytbl()
            {
                name = bnameTextBox.Text,

                price = int.Parse(bpriceTextbox.Text),
                date = dateTimePicker1.Value,
                deadline = dateTimePicker2.Value,
                buyername = bbuyerTextBox.Text,
                count = int.Parse(bcountTextBox.Text)



            };
            if (bpriceTextbox == null)
            {
                String a = "THE FIELD IS NULL!";
                MessageBox.Show(a);
            }

            database.buytbls.Add(tbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = database.buytbls.ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="masterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SMQ2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="notebookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/namadModel.csdl|res://*/namadModel.ssdl|res://*/namadModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=smq2;initial catalog=notebook;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Thank you guys!...

Comment: Any error? did you followed code first or database first approach.

Comment: I forgot that I what did first... I don't get any error

Comment: I got this now: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The 'price' property on 'buytbl' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'

Comment: set price column nullable as you are trying to insert null value in non null column.

Comment: I had add on column in the last ( 2 days ago ...! ) and now when I click on add button, DataGridView show me the last one.. not the new on that I adding now..

Comment: call database.SaveChanges(). Otherwise the changes made in the context won't be mirrored in the database.

Comment: write down, your buytbl class which contains the the price property.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
database.buytbls.Add(tbl);
```

You add an entity to your database context

But to commit your added entity, you need to do

```
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have SaveChanges in a partial class

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question, but extremely important: You should not reuse database context over multiple operations. Inside the button1_Click, create new database context instance, add an object to it and then call SaveChanges. Then, the data will appear.

And now the answer. SaveChanges must be called between these two lines:

```
database.buytbls.Add(tbl);
database.SaveChanges(); // <---- This line is missing
dataGridView1.DataSource = database.buytbls.ToList();
```

The reason why data do not appear is in the way in which DbContext works. The last line, setting the DataSource, doesn't fetch data contained inside the DbContext, but rather runs another query on the database. And, since SaveChanges was not invoked, data are not in the database yet. That is why new data do not appear in the grid.